# Picasa Custom Button Problem

Tags: api, button, picasa

I have started creating a custom button for Picasa to be able to upload some photos to a website. I followed the guidance found [here](http://code.google.com/apis/picasa/). It works fine so far but now I have made a small change to the button and picasa will not refresh the button no matter what I try.

Adding a link like this:

```
<a  href="picasa://importbutton/?url=http://www.acme-inc.com/acme-inc-photo-uploader.pbz"> Acme  Inc. Uploader</a>
```

to a page with access to your PBZ file will cause Picasa to open and instal the button. I made a small change and tried again. It updated once but now it refuses. I tried changing the name of the button, the version of the button, nothing works. Only the original button remains in Picasa. I even remove the button from picasa, reboot just in case its in memory somewhere, then tried again and still only original button remain.

The google group associated with the API does not appear to be very active. One other person asked about the same thing but there was no response. Searching the web found no other answers. I hope someone here has some experience with this.

I found a buttons folder in the picasa folder on the hard drive but my custom button was not in there. I have no idea why it keeps finding the old button.

I am using Picasa 3.1.0 on Windows XP if that makes any difference.

So the question: does anybody have experience building these custom buttons and/or encountered this situation before?

Thanks